# How to multiply functions in python?

Tags: python, function, monkeypatching, function-composition

```
def sub3(n):
    return n - 3

def square(n):
    return n * n
```

It's easy to compose functions in Python:

```
>>> my_list
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> [square(sub3(n)) for n in my_list]
[9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
```

Unfortunately, to use the composition as a *key* it's awkward, you have to use them in *another* function which calls both functions in turn:

```
>>> sorted(my_list, key=lambda n: square(sub3(n)))
[3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

This should really just be `sorted(my_list, key=square*sub3)`, because heck, function `__mul__` isn't used for anything else anyway:

```
>>> square * sub3
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'function'
```

Well let's just define it then!

```
>>> type(sub3).__mul__ = 'something'
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'function'
```

D'oh!

```
>>> class ComposableFunction(types.FunctionType):
...     pass
...
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    type 'function' is not an acceptable base type
```

D'oh!

```
class Hack(object):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        def hack(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.function(other(*args, **kwargs))
        return Hack(hack)
```

Hey, now we're getting somewhere..

```
>>> square = Hack(square)
>>> sub3 = Hack(sub3)
>>> [square(sub3(n)) for n in my_list]
[9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
>>> [(square*sub3)(n) for n in my_list]
[9, 4, 1, 0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36]
>>> sorted(my_list, key=square*sub3)
[3, 2, 4, 1, 5, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But I don't want a `Hack` callable class! The scoping rules are different in ways I don't fully understand, and it's arguably even uglier than just using the "lameda". Is it possible to get composition working directly with functions somehow?

Comment: have never seen anything similar to this, have you tried using `partials` instead, similar to `Hack` but maybe marginally better

Comment: @MalikBrahimi that isn't function composition, which is what wim wants. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_composition

Comment: There is a *long* thread on adding function composition (using the upcoming matrix multiplication operator `@`, since function composition is more similar to matrix multiplication than regular multiplication) on the python-ideas mailing list. The short summary, though, is that it's not going to happen any time soon, if at all.

Comment: @chepner do you have a link to the thread?

Comment: Here's [a link](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-May/thread.html) to the archives for May. It's a bit of a mess to follow, since the [initial message](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2015-May/033282.html) that started the thread had no subject, and it wound up as 2 or 3 parallel threads. One of the more interesting ideas to pop up (IMO) was rather than actually compose functions, just make a *tuple* of functions callable, so that `(f, g, h)(x) == f(g(h(x)))`.

Comment: One way or another you are going to need to multiply the functions after passing the argument either in the function type or as an individual function.

Comment: Oh!  The tuple idea sounds cool.

Comment: Anything that gets rid of the (stacks (of (parens (to (balance!)))))

Comment: I hate to say it, but I don't find anything wrong with the `lambda`. Although callable tuples would be cool.

Comment: You could create a decorator that makes a function composable by having it wrap your to-be-composed function in a callable class, and then overriding the `__mul__` method; alas, it'd be a bit of work and hand-waving, since you can't subclass `function` or `FunctionType` directly...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use your hack class as a decorator pretty much as it's written, though you'd likely want to choose a more appropriate name for the class.

Like this:

```
class Composable(object):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.function(*args, **kwargs)
    def __mul__(self, other):
        @Composable
        def composed(*args, **kwargs):
            return self.function(other(*args, **kwargs))
        return composed
    def __rmul__(self, other):
        @Composable
        def composed(*args, **kwargs):
            return other(self.function(*args, **kwargs))
        return composed
```

You can then decorate your functions like so:

```
@Composable
def sub3(n):
    return n - 3

@Composable
def square(n):
    return n * n
```

And compose them like so:

```
(square * sub3)(n)
```

Basically it's the same thing you've accomplished using your hack class, but using it as a decorator.

Comment: Neat.  I made a slight improvement, so now composition works with any other callables for example `(sub3*int)("10") --> 7` and `(str*sub3)(10) --> '7'`

Answer (score 2):

Python does not (and likely will never) have support for function composition either at the syntactic level or as a standard library function. There are various 3rd party modules (such as [functional](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/functional/0.7.0)) that provide a higher-order function that implements function composition.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
class Composition(object):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.functions = args

    def __call__(self, arg):
        result = arg
        for f in reversed(self.functions):
            result = f(result)

        return result
```

And then:

```
sorted(my_list, key=Composition(square, sub3))
```

Comment: Why not use a closure instead?

Comment: Closure is fine too. I don't see much difference between those approaches (except that with class you can modify functions list after composition creation).

Answer (score 2):

You can compose functions using [SSPipe library](https://github.com/sspipe/sspipe):

```
from sspipe import p, px

sub3 = px - 3
square = px * px
composed = sub3 | square
print(5 | composed)
```