# How to make all combinations of many functions in python?

Tags: python

So i have

```
x = 3 

def first(x):
    return x+2

def second(x):
    return x/2

def third(x):
    return x*4
```

I would like to make a pipe of functions like :

first -> second -> third

but all combinations of functions :
like first -> second , first -> third

and get each time the value of x for each combination.

And i don't need not only to multiply them but to be able to make multiple combination of various length.

Here it's just fixed number of combination : 
[How to multiply functions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195045/how-to-multiply-functions-in-python)

regards and thanks

Comment: @wim there 's not the combination theme and different size of combination in the answer you marked as duplicate.

Comment: OK, fair enough.  Re-opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the combinations part:

```
>>> functions = [first, second, third]
>>> from itertools import combinations, permutations
>>> for n in range(len(functions)):
...     for comb in combinations(functions, n + 1):
...         for perm in permutations(comb, len(comb)):
...             print('_'.join(f.__name__ for f in perm))
...             
first
second
third
first_second
second_first
first_third
third_first
second_third
third_second
first_second_third
first_third_second
second_first_third
second_third_first
third_first_second
third_second_first
```

Next the composing part, steal the `@Composable` decorator from the question [How to multiply functions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30195045/674039) and use it to compose functions from each permutation.

```
from operator import mul
from functools import reduce
for n in range(len(functions)):
    for comb in combinations(functions, n + 1):
        for perm in permutations(comb, len(comb)):
            func_name = '_'.join(f.__name__ for f in perm)
            func = reduce(mul, [Composable(f) for f in perm])
            d[func_name] = func
```

Now you have a namespace of functions (actually callable classes), demo:

```
>>> f = d['third_first_second']
>>> f(123)
254.0
>>> third(first(second(123)))
254.0
>>> ((123 / 2) + 2) * 4
254.0
```