# How can I use an operator to compose functions?

Tags: python-3.x, python-decorators, function-composition

It's fairly straightforward to write a function that composes two other functions. (For simplicity, assume they are one parameter each.)

```
def compose(f, g):
    fg = lambda x: f(g(x))
    return fg

def add1(x):
    return x + 1

def add2(x):
    return x + 2

print(compose(add1, add2)(5))  # => 8
```

I would like to do composition using an operator, e.g., `(add1 . add2)(5)`.

Is there a way to do that?

I tried various decorator formulations, but I couldn't get any of them to work.

```
def composable(f):
  """
    Nothing I tried worked. I won't clutter up the question 
    with my failed attempts.
  """

@composable
def add1(x):
    return x + 1
```

Comment: You mean you want to use an infix operator instead of standard prefix-calling notation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: defining my own operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/932328/python-defining-my-own-operators)

Comment: Related, maybe dupe:  [How to multiply functions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30195045/674039)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First only a certain amount of operator symbols are allowed in Python syntax. Dot "`.`" is not a valid operator.

[This page](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/operator.html) (the page is actually about the Python `operator` module, but the naming convention are the same to [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) and the content is more organized) listed all available operators and the corresponding instance methods. For example, if you want to use "`@`" as the operator, you can write a decorator like this:

```
import functools

class Composable:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return lambda *args, **kw: self.func(other.func(*args, **kw))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.func(*args, **kw)
```

To test:

```
@Composable
def add1(x):
    return x + 1

@Composable
def add2(x):
    return x + 2

print((add1 @ add2)(5))
# 8
```

Comment: Thanks. My confusion -- at least one of them -- was that dot was treated as an operator and that, __getattribute__ was the associated function. Also, I was trying to do it with a decorator function, rather than a decorator class. I'm going to leave your solution unchecked as *the answer* for now to see if another approach is suggested.

Comment: @RussAbbott I see what you mean. I don't think you can reload the `__getattribute__` method to access another function without passing the other function directly. It is true you can access a global function through `globals()`, but it is not recommended and you can not handle anonymous functions at all.

Comment: One of the problems I was having was the __getattribute__ seemed to get its argument as a string -- even when I was passing it a function. Don't know how to get around that.

Comment: I just tried a decorator function version of your solution. When it got to `print((add1 @ add2)(5))` I got an error message: `unsupported operand type(s) for @: 'function' and 'function'`. How does your approach avoid running into that problem?

Comment: Your approach works successfully if I replace `@` with `*` and `__matmul__` with `__mul__` or use `>` and .`__gt__` (It runs successfully even though PyCharm complains that a boolean isn't callable.) But as I said earlier, using `.` and `__getattribute__` fails because the argument to `__getattribute__` is converted to a string before being passed to `__getattribute__`.

Comment: I've continued this discussion as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162257/a-function-composition-operator-in-python,

Comment: Hello, is there an idea how to use ```@``` in a longer composition like ```f_1 @ f_2 @ f_3 (x)```.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without having to decorate all functions that you want to compose? E.g., by overriding `__lt__` in the class `function` globally?