# A function composition operator in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators, function-composition

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54153527/how-can-i-use-an-operator-to-compose-functions-in-python) I asked about a function composition operator in Python. [@Philip Tzou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2644759/philip-tzou) offered the following code, which does the job.

```
import functools

class Composable:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __matmul__(self, other):
        return lambda *args, **kw: self.func(other.func(*args, **kw))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.func(*args, **kw)
```

I added the following functions.

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    return lambda *args, **kw: self.func(other.func(*args, **kw))

def __gt__(self, other):
    return lambda *args, **kw: self.func(other.func(*args, **kw))
```

With these additions, one can use `@`, `*`, and `>` as operators to compose functions. For, example, one can write `print((add1 @ add2)(5), (add1 * add2)(5), (add1 > add2)(5))` and get `# 8 8 8`. (PyCharm complains that a boolean isn't callable for `(add1 > add2)(5)`. But it still ran.)

All along, though, I wanted to use `.` as a function composition operator. So I added

```
def __getattribute__(self, other):
    return lambda *args, **kw: self.func(other.func(*args, **kw))
```

*(Note that this fouls up `update_wrapper`, which can be removed for the sake of this question.)*

When I run `print((add1 . add2)(5))` I get this error at runtime: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'func'`. It turns out (apparently) that arguments to `__getattribute__` are converted to strings before being passed to `__getattribute__`.

Is there a way around that conversion? Or am I misdiagnosing the problem, and some other approach will work?

Comment: `other` in `__getattribute__` is the **name** of the attribute, it's not a binary operator like `>` or `@`.

Comment: As you saw, `.` is reserved for accessing attributes and methods. But you may use `°` which is more similar to the original operator, and will not create this problem.

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword what is the magic method to implement that?! It's not a valid Python operator.

Comment: Well it isn't a python operator ^^'

Comment: @FrenchMasterSword so... how exactly is that a useful suggestion? Are you suggesting the OP writes their own version of the interpreter to handle that symbol as an operator?

Comment: You probably want `__getattr__`, not `__getattribute__`. The former is called only when the attribute doesn't otherwise exist, the latter is called for **all** attributes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters they'll still get the string `'add2'` not the `Composable` object, though.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yes, good point. `__getattr__` can only deal with attribute **names**.

Comment: Related:  [How to multiply functions in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30195045/674039)

Comment: There is a very simple solution to your problem; drop the requirement that the operator should not be `*` or `@` and use one of those. IMHO these are much less confusing than if you'd actually succeed in using `.`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am actually unwilling to provide this answer. But you should know in certain circumstance you can use a dot "`.`" notation even it is a primary. This solution only works for functions that can be access from `globals()`:

```
import functools

class Composable:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __getattr__(self, othername):
        other = globals()[othername]
        return lambda *args, **kw: self.func(other.func(*args, **kw))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self.func(*args, **kw)
```

To test:

```
@Composable
def add1(x):
    return x + 1

@Composable
def add2(x):
    return x + 2

print((add1.add2)(5))
# 8
```

Comment: Very weird. But thank you very much for going to the trouble of providing this information.

Comment: This only works for globals **in the module `Composable` is defined in**. And while you could then start pulling out names from the stack, this still won’t give you full expression access; those would simply be syntax errors or parsed in the wrong order.

Comment: @RussAbbott not sure why you think this weird? You have a string, and `globals()` is a dictionary of the module namespace mapping strings to objects. So yes, if you limit yourself to globals in the same module you can map attribute names to globals this way. That’s an indirect path, just don’t expect to have the same expressive freedom as you have with the hooks for binary operators.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters. You're right. "Weird" is the wrong word. What I was reacting to was that this solution works in only limited situations -- as you also point out.

Answer (score 6):

You can't have what you want. The `.` notation is *not a binary operator*, it is a [primary](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#primaries), with only the value operand (the left-hand side of the `.`), and an *identifier*. [Identifiers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) are strings of characters, not full-blown expressions that produce references to a value.

From the [*Attribute references* section](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#attribute-references):

> An attribute reference is a primary followed by a period and a name:
>
> ```
> attributeref ::=  primary "." identifier
> ```
>
> The primary must evaluate to an object of a type that supports attribute references, which most objects do. This object is then asked to produce the attribute whose name is the identifier.

So when compiling, Python parses `identifier` as a string value, not as an expression (which is what you get for operands to operators). The `__getattribute__` hook (and any of the other [attribute access hooks](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access)) only has to deal with strings. There is no way around this; the dynamic attribute access function [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) strictly enforces that `name` must be a string:

```
>>> getattr(object(), 42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string
```

If you want to use syntax to compose *two* objects, you are limited to binary operators, so expressions that take two operands, and only those that have hooks (the boolean `and` and `or` operators do not have hooks because they evaluate lazily, `is` and `is not` do not have hooks because they operate on object identity, not object values).

Comment: I keep trying to find a way around this limitation, but I guess I'll have to give up. `@` and `*` are not that bad.

Comment: I asked a related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54164382/more-on-function-composition-and-decorators-in-python

Comment: It might also be worth noting here that, because the right-hand side of `.` must be an identifier, there is no way to override `.` such that `f . (g . h)` will work (or parse at all!), even with the `globals()` hack suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can step around the limitation of defining composable functions exclusively in the global scope by using the `inspect` module. Note that this is about as far from Pythonic as you can get, and that using `inspect` will make your code that much harder to trace and debug. The idea is to use `inspect.stack()` to get the namespace from the calling context, and lookup the variable name there.

```
import functools
import inspect

class Composable:

    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)

    def __getattr__(self, othername):
        stack = inspect.stack()[1][0]
        other = stack.f_locals[othername]
        return Composable(lambda *args, **kw: self._func(other._func(*args, **kw)))

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        return self._func(*args, **kw)
```

Note that I changed `func` to `_func` to half-prevent collisions should you compose with a function actually named `func`. Additionally, I wrap your lambda in  a `Composable(...)`, so that it itself may be composed.

Demonstration that it works outside of the global scope:

```
def main():
    @Composable
    def add1(x):
        return x + 1

    @Composable
    def add2(x):
        return x + 2

    print((add1.add2)(5))

main()
# 8
```

This gives you the implicit benefit of being able to pass functions as arguments, without worrying about resolving the variable name to the actual function's name in the global scope. Example:

```
@Composable
def inc(x):
    return x + 1

def repeat(func, count):
    result = func
    for i in range(count-1):
        result = result.func
    return result
    
print(repeat(inc, 6)(5))
# 11
```